# SMS Server to send SMS from Log of an Application

Tags: database, logging, sms

How can i send SMS from a Windows Server 2008 R2 ? SMS text should be log from a VMS application running on that server. Log exists in an MS SQL 2008 database. Once a log entry is updated in the log table in the database that log entry should be sms'ed automatically. What is the best way to do this ? I cant connect internet to this server as this is against the law.
There is a provision to sent SMTP mail on that application once an event exist. It would also be ok if we can send sms based on this smtp mail coming from this application.

Answer (score 0):

You likely don't want to try to use the email to SMS gateways some carriers provide (not the best route, sometimes blocked, etc).

However, you could create an external service that accepted email in the form of [number]-prefix@[yourdomain]. APIs like [SendGrid](http://sendgrid.com/) or [Postmark](https://postmarkapp.com/) provide APIs that take a incoming email, and turn it into a web request ([postmark](https://postmarkapp.com/inbound) / [sendgrid](http://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Webhooks/parse.html)).

You could then use a SMS API like [Nexmo](http://nexmo.com/) or [Twilio](http://www.twilio.com/) to send the SMS to the end user. Essentially building a simple email to SMS proxy for yourself.

Using both the Email and SMS APIs allows your proxy to be as simple as a single script, accepting inbound emails and turning them into SMS. Probably 20 or so lines of code (if that).

Alternatively, you could plug a phone (or even an Arduino with an SMS shield) into the server, and use a few libraries to send SMS directly from the device. That may be a bit more painful to maintain though.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use **hardware sms gateway**. It's a kind of device that serves as your own private SMS gateway. You buy it, connect it in your LAN, and send sms messages directly to GSM network.

- Pros: greater reliability and security (than using emails)
- Cons: costs money - needs your one-time investment

Example: [SMSEagle](http://www.smseagle.eu)

If you'll use a database event (trigger on update of your logs table) with a Powershell script ([see details on using Powershell support in SQL Server 2008](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd938892%28v=sql.100%29.aspx)) you can send SMS messages to your sms gateway in such way (Powershell script sends SMS to your gateway).

*Sample Powershell script to send SMS (HTTP request) to your hardware sms gateway:*

```
param(
  [string]$to = $(throw "Script usage: sendsms.ps1 -to -message "),
  [string]$message = $(throw "Script usage: sendsms.ps1 -to -message ")
)
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Web
$yourgatewayip = "192.168.0.101"
$yourgatewayusername = "john"
$yourgatewaypassword = "doe"
$smstext = [System.Web.HttpUtility]::UrlEncode($message)
$url = "http://$yourgatewayip/index.php/http_api/send_sms?login=$yourgatewayusername&pass=$yourgatewaypassword&to=$to&message=$smstext"
$client = New-Object system.Net.WebClient
$result = $client.downloadString($url)
Write-Host $result
```

*Caution: $url must be adjusted accordingly (depending on your particular device)*